# Implement a multithreaded stack in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack, thread-safety

> Implement a multi-threaded stack, with freedom to use existing
>   implementations of stack. On top of being thread-safe, it must block
>   (not busy-wait) a pushing thread when stack is full and a popping
>   thread when stack is empty. It must signal the threads out of sleep
>   when stack has space again or elements to pop. Fairness is optional in this question.

How can I implement such a stack in Java? I came up with below implementation. Is this the correct way to solve above problem?

```
public class MyStack<E> {
  private final Stack<E> stack;
  private int max = 16;
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
  private final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
  private final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();

  public MyStack(int size) {
    this.stack = new Stack<>();
    this.max = size;
  }

  public void push(E e) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (stack.size() == max) {
        notFull.await();
      }
      stack.push(e);
      notEmpty.signalAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public E pop() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (stack.size() == 0) {
        notEmpty.await();
      }
      E item = stack.pop();
      notFull.signalAll();
      return item;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Run it and see whether that works fine first.

Comment: Code review questions should be submitted here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: You should have used intrinsic locks instead of explicit locks here.

Comment: Thats something new for me so I am gonna read about that but what's the difference?

Comment: It's more simpler than this.

Comment: In general the idea is quite ok, but there are some issues, f.e. I don't think that swallowing of the `InterruptedException` is a good approach.

Comment: Out of curiosity, What's the use of a multi-threaded stack? Usually when you want a stack, it's because some algorithm requires that items be popped off in the exact reverse of the order that they were pushed on. But if items are used in different threads, then the "exact reverse" guarantee is lost. Queues often are used in multi-threaded applications, but in that case, the queue typically is a buffer between threads rather than an essential part of an algorithm, and it's OK if the items are only processed in _approximately_ the same order as pushed.